# python - simple way to add text and image to an image(for fb app) - PIL is hell in terms of dependency

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

for my facebook app, I am trying to generate image from the data. So, I need to put the text and some images on another background image . I thought of using PIL, but it had lot of dependencies which are making me mad. Also, at the end I have to do all these installations on heroku also . So, anyway simple way to add text and image to another image in python#Django ?

Some of the problems using pil : when using font feature, getting this error :  The _imagingft C module is not installed

I installed pillow also .

Answer (score 2):

You will need some form of an image processing library. Even some components of Django, like ImageField, need PIL.

If you are having problems building PIL, there is a fork called [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/#introduction), which supposedly aims to package it up better to make installation easier.

Comment: I too have had problems installing PIL, but, as mentioned, ImageField requires PIL so it's worth while to get it working. The trick is to make sure you install dependencies (libjpeg, libfreetype, etc) *before* you install PIL.